# Removing track from playlist call deleteContainer instead removeFromContainer

Tags: soap, sonos

When I am trying to remove tracks from users playlist, controller send SOAP request with method **deleteContainer**, i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
      <sessionId>574ae2c7e83b03.16748534_6f1bc18ac2878c101d2f28a0a4cdf2a8</sessionId>
      <deviceId>B8-E9-37-EF-29-1E:8</deviceId>
      <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
    </credentials>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <deleteContainer xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
      <id>TRACK:272228:13306</id>
    </deleteContainer>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But I can see there is a method [**removeFromContainer**](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/329) and I assume this method should be used for removing tracks from a playlist.

I have this problem in Android APP and in MacOS Sonos App. And I am removing tracks, not playlists. When removing playlists, it calls the same method **deleteContainer** but with the right ID, i.e.: **PLAYLISTS:PLAYLIST:23952**

Am I wrong? In which case method **removeFromContainer** will be used?

### Playlists root section

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
      <sessionId>574dd9f69e8ad1.86333620_6f1bc18ac2878c101d2f28a0a4cdf2a8</sessionId>
      <deviceId>B8-E9-37-EF-29-1E:8</deviceId>
      <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
    </credentials>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <getMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
      <id>playlists</id>
      <index>0</index>
      <count>100</count>
    </getMetadata>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:getMetadataResponse>
            <ns1:getMetadataResult>
                <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
                <ns1:count>2</ns1:count>
                <ns1:total>2</ns1:total>
                <ns1:mediaCollection readOnly="false" userContent="true" renameable="true">
                    <ns1:id>PLAYLISTS:PLAYLIST:23952</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:itemType>favorite</ns1:itemType>
                    <ns1:displayType>list</ns1:displayType>
                    <ns1:title>Another playlist</ns1:title>
                    <ns1:summary>39 songs 18486</ns1:summary>
                    <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
                    <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
                </ns1:mediaCollection>
                <ns1:mediaCollection readOnly="false" userContent="true" renameable="true">
                    <ns1:id>PLAYLISTS:PLAYLIST:28331</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:itemType>favorite</ns1:itemType>
                    <ns1:displayType>list</ns1:displayType>
                    <ns1:title>Some playlist</ns1:title>
                    <ns1:summary>21 songs 10454</ns1:summary>
                    <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
                    <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
                </ns1:mediaCollection>
            </ns1:getMetadataResult>
        </ns1:getMetadataResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

### Get playlist items

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
      <sessionId>574dd9f69e8ad1.86333620_6f1bc18ac2878c101d2f28a0a4cdf2a8</sessionId>
      <deviceId>B8-E9-37-EF-29-1E:8</deviceId>
      <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
    </credentials>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <getMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
      <id>PLAYLISTS:PLAYLIST:28331</id>
      <index>0</index>
      <count>100</count>
    </getMetadata>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:getMetadataResponse>
            <ns1:getMetadataResult>
                <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
                <ns1:count>21</ns1:count>
                <ns1:total>21</ns1:total>
                <ns1:mediaMetadata>
                    <ns1:id>TRACK:273257:14098</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:itemType>track</ns1:itemType>
                    <ns1:displayType></ns1:displayType>
                    <ns1:title>Dark Star</ns1:title>
                    <ns1:summary>Phil Lesh &amp; Friends</ns1:summary>
                    <ns1:mimeType>audio/mp3</ns1:mimeType>
                    <ns1:trackMetadata>
                        <ns1:artist>Phil Lesh &amp; Friends</ns1:artist>
                        <ns1:duration>1030</ns1:duration>
                        <ns1:rating>0</ns1:rating>
                        <ns1:albumArtURI>http://www.livedownloads.com/images/shows/phil160318_02.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
                        <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
                        <ns1:canSkip>true</ns1:canSkip>
                    </ns1:trackMetadata>
                </ns1:mediaMetadata>
                [other items]
            </ns1:getMetadataResult>
        </ns1:getMetadataResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

### On item remove from playlist

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
      <sessionId>574dd9f69e8ad1.86333620_6f1bc18ac2878c101d2f28a0a4cdf2a8</sessionId>
      <deviceId>B8-E9-37-EF-29-1E:8</deviceId>
      <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
    </credentials>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <deleteContainer xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
      <id>TRACK:263512:12867</id>
    </deleteContainer>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

### Environment

From MacOS Sonos app **About** dialog:

```
Version: 6.2.2
Build: 31927221
Sonos ID: 115034936
```

Sonos device info:

```
PLAY:1: Living Room
Serial Number: B8-E9-37-EF-29-1E:8
Version: 6.2 (build 31926010)
Hardware Version: 1.8.3.7-1
IP Address: 192.168.0.108
WM: 1
OTP:
```

From Android Sonos app

```
Sonos ID: 115034936
Version: 6.2.2 (build 31927151)
```

http://192.168.0.108:1400/status/VERSION

```
contents of /VERSION
31.9-26010
```

### Display type pmap

```
<DisplayType id="list">
    <DisplayMode>LIST</DisplayMode>
    <ItemThumbnails source="albumArtUri"/>
    <Lines>
        <Line token="title"/>
        <Line token="summary"/>
    </Lines>
</DisplayType>
```

Comment: You are correct in that removeFromContainer should be called.  Can you please update you question with a response that shows the playlist and a response that shows the playlist contents (the track you are trying to remove) as well as what version of the controller you are running?  Thanks.

Comment: Please, check my question again. More information added

Comment: Can you please post your pmap as I think this might help a lot in troubleshooting? Specifically it would be good to know the displayMode that is associated with the “list” displayType. Thanks.

Comment: Added pmap part for list

Comment: Please, let me know if you can reproduce this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way playlist editing was designed, the controller expects the individual playlist containers to be of itemType "playlist". The way to fix the behavior you are seeing above, is to set each of the individual playlist containers to itemType "playlist".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getMetadataResponse>
        <ns1:getMetadataResult>
            <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
            <ns1:count>2</ns1:count>
            <ns1:total>2</ns1:total>
            <ns1:mediaCollection readOnly="false" userContent="true" renameable="true">
                <ns1:id>PLAYLISTS:PLAYLIST:23952</ns1:id>
                <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
                <ns1:displayType>list</ns1:displayType>
                <ns1:title>Another playlist</ns1:title>
                <ns1:summary>39 songs 18486</ns1:summary>
                <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
                <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
            <ns1:mediaCollection readOnly="false" userContent="true" renameable="true">
                <ns1:id>PLAYLISTS:PLAYLIST:28331</ns1:id>
                <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
                <ns1:displayType>list</ns1:displayType>
                <ns1:title>Some playlist</ns1:title>
                <ns1:summary>21 songs 10454</ns1:summary>
                <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
                <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
        </ns1:getMetadataResult>
    </ns1:getMetadataResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Since the parent container has an itemType of "favorites", the children will also inherit the favorites behavior and you will still be able to have the content of the individual playlists refreshed upon the getLastUpdate call. You could also include the containsFavorite node within mediaCollection and set the value to true for the individual playlists (see documentation here on containsFavorite: http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/83).

We will investigate internally the behavior when an itemType other than "playlist" is used for individual playlist containers. Let us know if you have any further questions.